# jquery копирование HTML содержимого с значениями инпутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Доброго. Прошу вникнуть в вопрос!

```
//JQuery
var htmlform = $(".tableForm").html();
alert(htmlform);
```

Есть JQ команда, которая возвращает все HTML содержимое Тэга. Правда если в моем HTML содержится форма, в ней есть INPUTы. И INPUTы изначально НЕ заполнены, т.е.

```
value=""
```

а вот если их заполнить, и выполнить команду JQ описанную выше, то переменная htmlform по прежнему с пустым значением. Конечно можно выковырять его отдельно, но если полей много не вариант

Подскажите, как скопировать весь HTML с вписанными значениями в INPUT?

p.s.

```
//такое тоже не работает
var htmlform = $(".tableForm").get(0).outerHTML;
```

Comment: Скажите пожалуйста, зачем Вам необходим `html` формы? Может, для достижения конечной цели можно не использовать `html` формы.

Comment: про то, что это не правильно я в курсе. просто сейчас заказчики пошли, один лучше другого. цель именно сохранить весь HTML

Comment: Дело не в правильно\не правильно. Как я понял, цель - это сохранить `html`. Сохранить куда и зачем? И что значит сохранить?

Comment: HTML открывается из определенного файла, и в него же сохраняется. Так устроена система которую правлю. Остановился на варианте перед снятием HTML содержимого проходиться скриптом по инпутам и назначать им значения. Оказывается готовой команды JQ, нету ( если кто столкнется с такой задачей )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получаем массив из `input`, содержащиеся в блоке с классом `tableForm`:

```
var inputs = $(".tableForm > input");
```

Используем значения:

```
alert(inputs[0].value)
```

Answer (score 0):

С такой же проблемой столкнулся, но решил несколько иначе, путём копирования введённой инфы прямиком в value="" :

```
$('.step_1 input').change(function(){
    var texts = $(this).val();
    $(this).attr('value', texts);
});
```

В этом случае весь код скопировался правильно через .html() ;